# Show that there is a formula $A$ such that $T_{\Sigma \cup A}$ and $T_{\Sigma \cup \lnot A}$ are both consistent.

Tags: logic

Let $\Sigma=\{A,B,C,D,E\}$

$A\equiv \forall x e(x,x)$

$B\equiv \forall x \forall y e(x,y) \to e(y,x)$

$C\equiv \forall x \forall y \forall z( e(x,y) \land e(y,z))\to e(x,z)$

$D\equiv \forall x \forall ye(x,y)\to e(f(x),f(y))$

$E\equiv \forall x \forall y e(x,y) \to (p(x) \leftarrow \rightarrow p(y))$

Where $p$ is a predicate and $f$ is a function.

I have to show that there is no model $M$ such that $T_\Sigma=T_M$.

For this i have to find a formula $A$ such that $T_{\Sigma \cup A}$ and $T_{\Sigma \cup \lnot A}$  are both consistent.

$A$ has to be a closed formula.

$T_\Sigma$ is the theory produced from $\Sigma$

Can i get some help?

Comment: consistent also means satisfiable

Comment: Do you recognize the first three?  What do they say about $e$?

Comment: equivalence relation

Comment: And what do $D,E$ say about $f, p$?

Comment: i dont see how this helps

Comment: that they are also equivalence relations ?

Comment: No, they are not relations.  But they need to relate to $e$ properly.

Comment: I think it means that e is a congruence relation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66742/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-asddf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axioms say $e$ is an equivalence relation, that $f$ and $p$ respect the relation by having $f$ take all the elements in a given class to an image in another or the same class and having $p$ have the same truth value for all elements of the same class.  I can think of two statements that can be added.  One I can think of is $\forall x p(x)$.  This can clearly be added to your axioms without a problem.  Its negation is $\exists x \lnot p(x)$.  As long as there is at least one element in the universe, we can strengthen this to $\forall x \lnot p(x)$ and this is consistent as well.  As long as there are two elements in the universe another is $\exists x,y f(x) \neq f(y)$ or $\forall x,y f(x)=f(y)$ without a problem.

Comment: I understand the question and the comments and the answer,but I do not understand your statement by OP:I have to show that there is no model $M$ such that $T_\Sigma=T_M$. I can easily find many interpretations (models)) for \Sigma.

Comment: Please see updated the comment

Comment: @magma:  as I am used to it, it is incorrect to talk of $T_M$.  A theory is the set of consequences of a set of axioms.  I have found a sentence that is not decided by the first set of axioms, as shown by the fact that you can add either it or its negation to the axioms and get a consistent theory.  That means the theory with the sentence is a superset of the theory without it.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Exactly my point. So why does the OP say that there are no models for\Sigma?

Comment: @magma how i understand, there are models for $\Sigma$ just there isnt a model M such that $T _\Sigma = T_M$

Comment: By model i mean interpretation, im sorry if that confused you.

Comment: There are models for $\Sigma$, but each one makes $\forall x p(x)$ either true or false.  That shows that $T_{\Sigma}$ is not complete.  The best I can guess for $T_M$ is that it is a complete set of sentences true in the model $M$